# How can I get the equation of the parabola of the graphic?

Tags: geometry

[image]

How can I get the equation of the parabola of the graphic and draw it in geogebra, some help please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you read the graph.  If you think the minimum is the point at $x=0$ (which I don't think is clear-it could still be decreasing at that point), which I read as $y=16$, you have $y=ax^2+16$ and just need to find one other point to assess $a$. I want to see $(6,50)$, which would say $a=\frac {34}{36}$, but then I think problems like this use simple numbers, so I round to $1$ and say $y=x^2+16$

Answer (score 2):

From the graphics we see that the vertex is $V(0,c)$ where $c \approx 16$.For $x=5$, $y \approx 50$ Therefore the equation should be $y=2x^2+16$.